# Extension to Borel measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{B}(\tau)$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

**Question:** Under which conditions does a  measure $\mu:\mathscr{A}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$, defined on a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}\subset \mathscr{B}(\tau)$, extend to a Borel measure $\hat \mu:\mathscr{B}(\tau)\rightarrow [0,\infty]$? In particular I am interested in the case where $\mathscr{A}=\mathscr{B}(\tau')$ for some coarser topology $\tau'\subset \tau$.

---

If $\tau$ is generated by a metric $d$, then one approach is the following: Define $\mu^*:2^X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ by
$$
\mu^*(A)=\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \left[ \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i): A\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i, E_i\in \tau, \mathrm{diam}_d(E_i)<\delta\right\}
\right],$$
then according to a standard result in measure theory, $\mu^*$ is a metric outer measure and its restriction $\hat \mu = \mu^*\restriction\mathscr{B}(\tau)$ is a measure. In order for $\hat \mu$ to be an extension of $\mu$ it would thus suffice to show that $\mu=\mu^*\restriction \mathscr{A}$. Are there circumstances (in particular in the case that $\mathscr{A}=\mathscr{B}(\tau')$) in which this is possible to check easily?

Comment: How do you define the diameter of a set in a topological space?...Also you have a typo i believe..in the summation don't you have to use diam instead of $\mu$ ??

Comment: In the construction I assume that $\tau$ is induced by a metric and I take the diameter with respect to that metric. If I'd take the diameter instead of $\mu$, then there would be no hope to obtain an extension. I am using method 2 in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) wikipedia article.